# how to fixed Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthException

Tags: android

when I run the my android application give the two error message . how to correct it

Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthException;

Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthException;

Comment: can you please post you build.gradle file if you are using studio ?

Comment: I use eclipse  -@user1140237

Comment: Surely you included Google Play Services twice